# Disabled wp-cron, set up system cron but still have missed schedule posts

Tags: posts, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I have a caching plugin (WP Rocket) so I am aware of the issues with wp-cron and scheduled posts. So, I disabled **wp-cron** and then set up a system cron.  Now, I noticed that when a post is scheduled it's not set to **HH:MM:00** but has some number greater than **0** seconds. So, I set the system cron to run wp-cron at every 5 minutes and 35 minutes past the hour. And still I get missed schedule on posts. I know it runs as I have the output logged which shows a **200** return code plus I see my cache files with timestamps at 5 minutes and 35 minutes past the hour.

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Cron entry (I x'd out my user name.  I also have one for 35 minutes with output to wget35.log):

```
5   *   *   *   *   wget -o /home/xxxxx/logs/wget5.log https://www.jennystampsup.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron 2>/home/xxxxx/logs/wget5.err
```

### Update

Using WP-Control I see that the `check_and_publish_future_post` event for the post remains as an event after `wget` runs. I can run it manually from WP-Control and the `post_status` went to **publish**. If I run `wget` twice it works. The first `wget` took one second. The second took 17 seconds, but after it ran the `check_and_publish_future_post` fired. I will create a script that runs `wget` several times with some sleep statements and that should do it.

### Update 6/27

So, posts on my site are scheduled for **7:00:XX**. So, I wrote a script that hits `wp-cron.php` 10 times, sleeping two seconds in between each hit, and had it kick off in my system cron at **7:01**. And still `publish_future_post` did not fire. I looked at the WP Cron schedule prior to my script firing and there were 8 other cron events waiting to fire. They all fired. So, I went to Cloud9 and hit `wp-cron.php` from there. This caused the `publish_future_post` to fire. The only variables there are it is a different ip and time zone. Those should make no difference as far as I know. This is very puzzling.

Comment: Have you tried running the cron more frequently (eg., every five minutes via `*/5`) or plugins which promise to solve this, like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-missed-schedule-posts/)?

Comment: To run a cron entry in less than a half hour would violate my hosts terms of service.

Comment: I'd imagine so but, just to be sure: have you checked the posts are remaining unpublished in the back-end?

Comment: I will check tomorrow with the next scheduled post.

Comment: See my update above

Comment: See my next update for today.

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack's site map cron event was just before my `publish_future_post`; which takes some time to run (In fact, I found with inserting some debug statements into `wp-cron.php`, that it never returns back to `wp-cron.php`).  Using **WP Crontol** I moved it to after `publish_future_post`, and `publish_future_post` fired.  I am guessing hitting wp-cron below the `WP_CRON_LOCKOUT_TIMEOUT` threshold of its default value of **60 secs** was preventing `publish_future_post` from firing.  When I hit wp-cron from Cloud 9 it was two minutes later, so `publish_future_post` was able to fire.

So, while moving control of WP Cron to the system cron is an accepted pattern, it seems it does not solve all the problems with WP Cron.  I suppose I could add a `sleep 60` in my script between each hit to overcome the issue of cron event that does not return control to `wp-cron.php` but such a script would be a long running script.  And as noted above I cannot schedule a cron event in less than 30 minutes from a prior one as it would violate my hosts cron policy.

So, as long as a post is never scheduled for 7:30 am or pm, and the sitemap cron event never changes back to its original time I should be good.

I will contact Automatic and see what they say.

Comment: Automatic is looking into issue with sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

With **WP CLI** I was able to avoid other plugins potentially interfering with `publish_future` post.

Below is a **perl** fragment. On my host webdir is `$HOME/public_html` and bindir is `/usr/bin`. Note the use of `--due-now`.  Only those hooks currently waiting to be fired will run.  Also note you either need to `cd` into webdir or add `--path=path`, where path is the path to the wordpress files (usually webdir).

```
# Post any scheduled posts ready to publish
my $cmd = "cd <webdir>; <bindir>/wp cron event run publish_future_post --due-now;
system($cmd);

# Run other cron events normally
$cmd = "cd <webdir>; <bindir>/php wp-cron.php";
system($cmd);
```

Then I set the script to run at **1,31** in my system cron as all posts either are scheduled for the top of the hour or the bottom of the hour.